# how can extract information from xml file with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

i have this xml file

```
<A>
    <aa IRI="X"/>
    <bb IRI="X1"/>
    <bb IRI="X2"/>
</A>
<A>
    <aa IRI="Y"/>
    <bb IRI="Y1"/>
    <bb IRI="Y2"/>
</A>
<A>
    <aa IRI="Z"/>
    <bb IRI="Z1"/>
    <bb IRI="Z2"/>
</A>
```

.
.
.

in my xml file, it contains big number of A balise
so how can i extract the bb atribute (IRI) when aa IRI="Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, like so:

```
//A[aa/@IRI='Y']/bb/@IRI
```

(Find me the `A` which has an `aa` child element with `IRI` attribute of `Y`, then navigate to the `bb` subelement and retrieve the `IRI` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `precending-sibling`:

```
//A/bb[preceding-sibling::aa[@IRI="Y"]]/@IRI
```

Demo (using `xmllint` tool):

```
$ cat input.xml 
<test>
    <A>
        <aa IRI="X"/>
        <bb IRI="X1"/>
        <bb IRI="X2"/>
    </A>
    <A>
        <aa IRI="Y"/>
        <bb IRI="Y1"/>
        <bb IRI="Y2"/>
    </A>
    <A>
        <aa IRI="Z"/>
        <bb IRI="Z1"/>
        <bb IRI="Z2"/>
    </A>
</test>
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath '//A/bb[preceding-sibling::aa[@IRI="Y"]]/@IRI'
 IRI="Y1" IRI="Y2"
```